# AWS Policy for all resources related to a specific Amplify project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-policies

I have an Amplify project, I want to restrict users to be able to modify only resources related to it.
I thought to create a new AWS Policy that have permissions to do anything on all resources including a specific string.
I got an error: "Failed to save changes to policy .
Resource vendor must be fully qualified and cannot contain regexes."

This is what I tried to do:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:*:*:*:*stringname*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would appreciate if you'll help me to find a solution (even other solution than the one mentioned above).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via tags on resources. Something like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "policy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {"aws:ResourceTag/project": "${aws:PrincipalTag/project}"}
            }
        }]
}
```

This assumes that you added `project` tag to resources and to IAM users. You could omit the tag from the users, if instead you set condition as:

```
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {"aws:ResourceTag/project": "projectname"}
            }
```